# What is the meaning of "Artisanal landlord price hike sale" ?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across this phrase in an article today, I didn't get the sense of the whole sentence together. would anyone break it into pieces for me please.
bundle of thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to us native English speakers, either.

Comment: Also, "price  hike sale" sounds illogical.

Comment: You'd simply have to quote a long section of the article, to find an answer.

Comment: http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/06/14/brooklyn-deli-s-artisinal-price-hike-is-no-joke.html?source=TDB&via=FB_Page                                      

please give a look at the link of the article, the phrase in question is written on a poster within the head photo

Comment: @AhmedIdrisMergahni Did you read that article? It seems to explain what is happening pretty clearly. (The headline is intentionally made nonsensical)

Comment: yes, I have read it, and if I am not wrong I think the phrase probably means that sale prices have been increased due to the increasing in rental rates. But my question stems from the theme if I passed by this poster, it would be pretty hard for me to perceive it from the first time.

Comment: There's more of it [here](https://instagram.com/p/31I-wqhlUn/) and [here](http://bayridgejournal.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/fighting-gentrification-one-artisanal.html). I'd say it's just deliberately meaningless juxtaposition. Unquestionably the "true" meaning of ***artisanal*** would have no relevant significance to most of the people using or reading it, but I suppose at least a few are thinking in terms of *artisans = the workers = **ordinary people*** (who have to pay rent to avaricious landlords).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you for your explanation, but what is the massage of such posters, let us take for example the poster which you have shared with me "Artisanal Roach Bombs", what is the meaning that the store want to disseminate?

Comment: @Ahmed Idris Mergahni: There's not necessarily *any* "meaning" in the sense I suspect you're thinking of (certainly not to the vast majority of people who might encounter the usage). But my guess is the original person was 90% thinking simply in terms of meaningless juxtaposition for the sake of "interest", with a tiny nod to the idea that those landlords who hike the rent are "pests, parasites, vermin" preying on the workers. Don't overthink it - he probably didn't.

Comment: I'm not particularly aware of "roach bomb" either, but I take it for granted that's a "smoke bomb" kind of pesticide treatment to clear your house of cockroaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As comments have already stated, this is quite nonsensical at first blush. Having read the article, however, it becomes clear how it is meant to be understood:

A *price hike* is an increase in prices. In this case, the person raising the ‘prices’ (here: the rent) is the landlord, so this is a *landlord price hike*, as it were. Jesse’s Deli is now having a ‘sale’, in an ironic kind of way: they are raising the prices to match the raised rent imposed by the landlord.

In English marketing-speak, the word *sale* is frequently modified by some kind of phrase that tells you **why** there is a sale on: Christmas sale, back-to-school sale, just-because-we-can sale, etc. This works the same: Jesse’s Deli’s sale is a *landlord-price-hike sale* (an ironic ‘sale’ brought on by the landlord’s rental price hike).

An *artisan* is, roughly speaking, someone who works in a particular trade in an old-fashioned, ‘crafty’, skilled way. Someone who makes things himself the way he was taught by his old master; not someone who works in a factory making things in automated processes on machines. Jesse’s Deli is an *artisan store*, a small store with a large amount of human touch, free of the sterile conveyor-belt feeling of big supermarkets.

Since Jesse’s Deli is an artisanal store, this ‘sale’ is also artisanal: it is an *artisanal landlord-price-hike sale*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquect you made it crystal clear for me, thank you a million. Actually, I thought that, the phrase in question is a common phrase that has a specific meaning. It is clear right now.

Comment: No, it's still not a common phrase,  and hopefully it will never become so. However, kudos to Janus for a well-written answer informed by close reading

Comment: @Rache, what I meant to say is, at the outset, when I read the phrase at the first time, I thought it has a common meaning, but after the blow-by-blow explanation from Mr.Janus Bahs Jacquet, I began to see the light.